# How to Merge the Headers of multiple columns in HTSQL

Tags: htsql

I am making a Table in HTSQL, which results like:

```
Name  Total_Calls  Successful_Calls  Failed_Calls
John       9              5                4
```

Where as I want to merge the headers like:

```
           C  A  L  L  S
Name  Total  Successful  Failed
John    9        5          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :as to rename a column (total_calls to total)
and then use brackets to mark your nested record.  Here is
an example:

http://demo.htsql.org/student%7Bid,%20start_date,%20%7Bname%20:as%20full_name,%20gender%20:as%20sex,%20dob%20:as%20birth_date%7D%20:as%20personal_information%20%7D